# Fetching image from photolibrary/album is not working on ipad

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on a phonegap (versino -4.0) application and we have a functionality to get image either from camera or from photo library.

the code we are using for getting image from photolibrary is

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
```

This is the example from [here](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/phonegap1.9/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

By this code photolibrary is loading in iphone but not working on iPad.

Can you please guide us if anything wrong is here?
Thank you so much for any hint or solution.

Comment: Check camera permission first on device.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try 
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,

    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL

});
```

Also I think popover must be involved for iPad. Check examples again from your link. 
      setTimeout(function() { 
     // do your thing here!
     }, 0);

Comment: I have checked the setTimeout(function() { // do your thing here! }, 0); but not getting where should I place this. Can you please guide? Thank You!